# Adding HttpSession Object to Infinispan cache

Tags: session, caching, infinispan

We have started using infinispan cache with wildfly 13 in our web application. The web application is deployed in wildfly domain mode in a cluster of two node with one  acting as master and the other as slave. In the application we have an admin feature, where the admin can terminate a user.

So what we want to do is add session objects to Infinispan cache and retrieve it and terminate it when required. I am aware that HttpSession object is not serializable hence it cannot be added to cache but every attribute added to the session object is serilizable so my question is, is there a workaround for the issue?  Because right now we get a NotSerializable error when I try to add session to cache and it's also no longer possible to retrieve session from sessionId and terminate it due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to manually interact with the Infinispan cache: WildFly transparently supports full http session clustering with Infinispan. See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/High+Availability+Guide

Comment: Hi Tristan. Does this mean that my application can see sessions on both servers? Because that does not happen with mine, it can only see sessions on the server the instance of the application is open on.

Comment: Have you added the <distributable/> element to your web.xml ?

Comment: Yes Tristan I have added the <distributable/> tag to my web.xml